# Did Yokodera receive all of Ponta's worldly desires?

Tags: hentai-ouji-to-warawanai-neko

When Ponta visited the unsmiling cat statue at the beginning of the series, he offered his dakimakura (body pillow) named Barbara-san as a symbol of his worldly desires. Consequently, the statue took them his desires from him, and he turned to a life of helping the poor starving children of Africa.

The ability of the unsmiling cat statue is to "take something you don't want and shove it on someone else." And, it just so happens that Yokodera ends up with Barbara-san, the symbol of Ponta's worldly desires. So we might expect that Yokodera ended up with Ponta's desires as well, especially based on how the cat statue seems to work in later chapters. On the other hand, it doesn't seem like Yokodera's desires change drastically, at least not until he himself makes an offering at the statue.

Is this confirmed anywhere in the original light novels or any other official source that Yokodera does also gain Ponta's desires when he receives Barbara-san?